# How to trigger the open function for react-dropzone-component using refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, react-dropzone

I am using the react drop-zone component to upload files to the server.

I would like to call the drop-zone open function on button click.

This is what I have tried so far:

I am using `refs` to reference the drop zone. Also note I have multiple drop-zone's

```
<DropzoneComponent
  style={{ height: 80 }}
  ref={this.myRef}
  config={config}
  eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
  djsConfig={djsConfig}
  />
```

And on a separate button click I am calling a function

```
  openDropZone1 = () => {
    this.refs.myRef.open();
    this.setState({
      bankStatement1: true,
      bankStatement2: false,
      bankStatement3: false
    });
  };
```

On click of the button I get the following error:-

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
>   on this line  `this.refs.myRef.open();`

Any help or suggestion is most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: can you use like this ref={(node)=>this.drop=node}
and in the openDropZone1 function use this.drop.open()

Comment: it should probably be this.myRef.open(); !!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @ShivaSai but I get the same error.

Comment: @tjadli it still gives the same error.

Comment: @anup, did you declare your ref ?      this.myRef = React.createRef();
if it's already the case, you should post a more detailed code for us to see the problem !

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/file-dialog

This is the final answer because it's in the docs if this doesn't solve your problem then it is something wrong with your code

Comment: Thank you Shiva but it still gives the same error. Have you implemented it yourself. If yes can you share the code in the answer itself.

Comment: @anup here is the working example for your problem https://codesandbox.io/s/lmnlwwj4l

Comment: I am using a different library for drop zone. Here is a link for the same https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component

Comment: @anup can you change the library

Comment: The final answer link now 404s.

Comment: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/file-dialog